# Unable to update TextView with Timer in separate class

Tags: java, android, class, timer, textview

I've created a timer and placed it in its own separate class. For some reason when I try to run it it crashes with the following error:

Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

I think it because its trying to update a textview from a class other than Mainactvity but I cant figure out how to get it to work.

Here's the code:

MainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button resetButton;
TextView textTimer;
int elapsedTime;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    elapsedTime = 60;


    textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);

    final Button resetbttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetbttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CountUp mycountup = new CountUp();
            mycountup.count();
        }
    });

}

}
```

Timer Class:

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

/**
 * Created by Mat on 24-Feb-17.
 */

```
public class CountUp extends MainActivity{




TextView textTimer;
Button resetButton;
int elapsedTime;
Handler h;
int RATE = 1000;
MainActivity mainact = new MainActivity();




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);



h = new Handler();

count();

final Button resetbttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
resetbttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        reset();
    }
});
}

public void reset(){
    elapsedTime = 60000;
}




public void count(){
    elapsedTime--;
    textTimer.setText(String.valueOf(elapsedTime));
    h.postDelayed(r,RATE);
    final String endcomparison = textTimer.getText().toString();
    if (endcomparison.equals("0")){
        reset();
    }
}
private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        count();
    }
};



}
```

Comment: I think I've moved this on now. I have added the following to the Main activity: "public static TextView hourtext;" and "hourtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SessionTimerTxt);". In the timer class I have changed this "hourtext.setText (String.valueOf(elapsedTime))" to this "MainActivity.hourtext.setText(String.valueOf(elapsedTime));". I now get a different error which is "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)' on a null object reference" HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your are just instantiating an activity, which it's onCreate will never get called.

```
CountUp mycountup = new CountUp();
mycountup.count(); // view never created so it's null
```

To load the views you need to use a method like [startActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)).

If I am understanding you correctly, if you are extending CountUp from MainActivity then in your manifest, you'd set CountUp as your launching activity. Then using Java inheritance, you don't need to re-find the views, because in CountUp we are calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState), which calls the MainActivity's onCreate.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button resetButton;
TextView textTimer;
int elapsedTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  elapsedTime = 60;
  textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
  resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
  }
 }

public class CountUp extends MainActivity{
  Handler h;
  int RATE = 1000;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // can access this since inheritance
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          reset();
      }
   });
    h = new Handler();
    count();
  }

//...

public void count(){
  elapsedTime--;

  // inheritance   
  textTimer.setText(String.valueOf(elapsedTime));
  h.postDelayed(r,RATE);
  final String endcomparison = textTimer.getText().toString();
  if (endcomparison.equals("0")){
      reset();
  }
 }
 //...
}
```

Comment: Hi Ekeitho, thanks for the response. It looks like you've just put the timer code into the mainActivity? If I want to avoid that as I'll have several different timers and the code in MainActivity will be huge!

Comment: Ok, got what you were trying to do now then. Then your CountUp class doesn't need to extend from Activity. Your CountUp just needs a reference to the Activity like passing it into your CountUp constructor and mutate your view inside of CountUp. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

findViewById() method actually looks for view in layout file.
when you set layout for activity or fragment using

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

findViewById() find those views in that layout. it can't find random objects on the fly.

so in second activity set layout first or create sub class in first activity and then try to update data in textview.

Comment: Hi androidnoobdev, thanks for the response. Ah ok, so I have to identify the layout and then it'll know where to search for the view ID. I'll give this a go and see if it works. So basically I just need to add this "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" to my second activity and it should work :-)

Comment: @Matmajot Ya but that will display that layout. I mean 2 times you will see same layout. so you rather pass text view object into second class and then update it.

Comment: ok, so how do I pass that textview object into the second class, could you provide me with an example? Thanks